# How do i place a double dash between values in an output (I'm using Python)?

Tags: python, fibonacci

So I'm making a program that prints every value from 1 to a given input in the Fibonacci sequence and its for a class I'm in. He wants us to make it so that when the outputs are printed, they are all separated by double dashes. For example: 1 -- 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 5 and so on. My question is how do I make it do this instead of commas between output values?
Please don't say anything about how long my code is , but here's what I have so far:
    t = False

```
def comma(num):
    if type(num) == int:
        return '{:,}'.format(num)
    elif type(num) == float:
        return '{:,.2f}'.format(num)
    else:
        print("Need a number to function comma")
def fib(limit):
    numbers = ["0","1"]
    x3 = 1
    x2 = 1
    x1 = 1
    while x3 <= int(limit):
        if x3 >=999:
            n = [(comma(x3))]
        numbers = numbers + n
        x1 = x2 
        x2 = x3
        x3 = x2 + x1
    return(numbers)
def isint(value):
    try:
        int(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
def printFib():
    b = False
    while b == False:
        limit = input("What is the limit value?")
        if isint(limit):
            2 + 2
            if int(limit) >= 1 and int(limit) != 1 and int(limit) <= 8944394323791464:
                b = True
            else:
                if int(limit) == 0 or int(limit) == 1:
                    print("really it can't start.")
                elif int(limit) >= 8944394323791464:
                    print("Too big, just too big.")
                else:
                    print("Use positive numbers above one, or I will tell Antonio Montoya that you killed his father and he will find you.")
        else:
            print("Use whole numbers.")
    print(str(fib(limit)))
    if input("Try again y/n?") == "y":
        printFib()
printFib()
```

Comment: My favourite line: `2 + 2`

Comment: You should pare your code down into an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @GPhilo minus one that's three, quick maths !

Comment: Consider using the `'--'.join()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
print(str(fib(limit)))
```

with

```
print('--'.join(fib(limit)))
```

You might wish to add spaces around the `--` (you say *separated by double dashes* but your example shows double dashes with spaces).

In addition, in the function `fib()` you need to initialise `n`, probably with `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
def fib(limit):
    numbers = ["0","1"]
    x3 = 1
    x2 = 1
    x1 = 1
    while x3 <= int(limit):
        numbers.append(str(x3))
        x1 = x2 
        x2 = x3
        x3 = x2 + x1       
    return(numbers)

def isint(value):
    try:
        int(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def printFib():
    b = False
    while b == False:
        limit = raw_input("What is the limit value?")
        if isint(limit):
            if int(limit) >= 1 and int(limit) != 1 and int(limit) <= 8944394323791464:
                b = True
            else:
                if int(limit) == 0 or int(limit) == 1:
                    print("really it can't start.")
                elif int(limit) >= 8944394323791464:
                    print("Too big, just too big.")
                else:
                    print("Use positive numbers above one, or I will tell Antonio Montoya that you killed his father and he will find you.")
        else:
            print("Use whole numbers.")
    print('--'.join(fib(limit)))
    if raw_input("Try again y/n?") == "y":
        printFib()

printFib()
```